# Facebook - Image upload to fan page via Graph API not showing in public

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, image-upload

Followed by [this tutorial](http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/12/upload-photos-to-facebook-fan-page.html) I uploaded some pictures to my fan page album ( Timeline photos ) using graph API. Every thing working fine but

User's , public can't see the uploaded images. Only I ( Page ) can see the images. Even if the particular image's permission has been set to "public".

Any idea ? Any permission issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, if the app is in "sandbox" mode, the images will only be visible to the admin/developers/tester users. Public users will not see the images

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - it looks like you need both 'manage_pages' and 'publish_stream' permissions for the user - 'manage_pages' on it's own will let you upload photos, and return success, but the photo won't be visible to anyone.